# Double Angle Formula?

Tags: trigonometry

I am just trying to figure out what formula I would use to solve this equation. The problem is solve $\cos(3\theta)=1/2$; for all $0\leq \theta\leq 360^\circ$. I want to say I would use the double angle formula but I am not positive.

Answer (score 6):

Use the fact that $\cos{x}=\cos{y}\iff x=\pm y+2\pi n$.

So we have $$\cos{3\theta}=\frac{1}{2}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\\implies3\theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n\\\implies\theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{2\pi n}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the double angle formula to solve this one!

$\cos(3\theta)=1/2$

$3\theta=\cos^{-1}(1/2)$

$\cos^{-1}(1/2)=60$ (in degrees)

$3\theta=60$

$\theta=20$

but hang on a second!! there are more solutions within $0\leq \theta\leq 360^\circ$. ... actually this domain must be modified for $3\theta$ since you need the answer to $3\theta$ not just $\theta$ like this:

$3*0\leq 3*\theta\leq 3*360^\circ$

$0\leq 3\theta\leq 1080^\circ$

(this is because the "3" modifies the frequency of the cosine curve. If you need more help with this concept tell me)

You actually have 6 correct answers to this question! one of them is the $20
$
 degrees. so...

$3\theta=60$ and so $\theta=20$

or

$3\theta=60+360$ ... $3\theta=420$ and so $\theta=140$

or

$3\theta=60+360+360$ ... $3\theta=780$ ...and so $\theta=260$

or

$3\theta=60+360+360+360+360$ ... $\theta=1140$ **which is out of domain**

That's 3 solutions. The other three can be brought from how the curve looks. which is $360-60$ which is $300$ degrees

so

$3\theta=300$ and so $\theta=100$

or

$3\theta=300+360$ ... $\theta=660$ and so $\theta=220$

or

$3\theta=300+360+360$ ... $\theta=1020$ and so $\theta=340$

or

$3\theta=300+360+306+306$ ... $\theta=1380$ **out of domain again**

So your solutions are "$20, 100, 140, 220, 260$ and $340$"!! I hope I made it through without errors.

Here's a brief proof for the working:

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Let $\phi=3\theta$. What angles $\phi$ between $0^\circ$ and $(3)(360^\circ)$ satisfy $\cos\phi=\frac{1}{2}$?

**Remark:** What is needed here could be called formulas, though I think of them as facts about the geometry of the cosine function. We switch to radians since you used them in your comment. We use the *periodicity* of cosine, which can be written as the formula $\cos(x+2k\pi)=\cos x$. The fact that $\cos(\pi/3)=\frac{1}{2}$ is one of those "special angle" facts that at one stage one is expected to remember. We also used the fact that $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x$, which is the fact that the cosine function is symmetric about $\pi$.

Comment: I have the 5 solutions which are theta= pie/9, 5pie/9, 7pie/9, 11pie/9, and 13pie/9. I just can't remember what formula I am supposed to use.

Comment: You seem to have switched to radians. Following my hint we get that $\phi$ is one of $\pi/3$, $5\pi/3$, $7\pi/3$, $11\pi/3$, $13\pi/3$, and $17\pi/3$. Divide by $3$ to get the values of $\theta$. Your list missed $17\pi/9$.

Comment: The way I got my list is to give the two solutions $\phi$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$, then add $2\pi$ to each, then add $2\pi$ to each.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas might help you here:

- the algebraic principle of performing inverse operations to isolate the variable.
- the idea that inverse trig functions (like $cos^{-1}$) are multi-valued - they return a set of possible real numbers rather than a single real number.  (i.e., rather than saying $cos^{-1}(1)$ = 0, we say that $cos^{-1}(1)$ = {$2 \pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$}.

Apply $cos^{-1}$ to both sides of your equation.  This gives two possible equations:

$ \\ 3 \theta = \frac{\pi}{3} + 2 \pi k_1, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \\$ or $ \\3 \theta = \frac{2 \pi}{3} + 2 \pi k_2, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \\$

Dividing both sides (of both equations) by 3 gives:

$\theta = \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2 \pi k_1}{3}, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$
or
$\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{9} + \frac{2 \pi k_2}{3}, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \\$

Notice that the division affects the $+ 2 \pi k$ (periodic) part.

Now find all solutions between 0 and $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* apply trigonometric formulae several times to find out that
$$\cos 3\theta \equiv 4\cos^3\theta - \cos\theta$$

However, solving $4\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta = \tfrac{1}{2}$ is no simpler, and in fact is much harder, than solving your original equation $\cos3\theta = \tfrac{1}{2}$. Solving this equations is really very easy.

If you want to find all solutions with $0 \le \theta \le 360^{\circ}$ then you need to find all solutions with $0 \le 3\theta \le 1080^{\circ}$. You can do this by plotting a graph, or by drawing a [CAST quadrant diagram](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&sqi=2&ved=0CEsQFjAN&url=http://thomaswhitham.pbworks.com/f/The%2bCAST%2bdiagram.pdf&ei=JDQeU5ufOJS0hAf75IH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNGlAKLoJNbaMk9S_4Ix1YsAa2DznA&bvm=bv.62788935,d.ZG4).

You will find that:

$$3\theta = \ldots,60^{\circ}, 300^{\circ}, 420^{\circ}, 660^{\circ}, \ldots$$

Dividing both sides by $3$ gives

$$\theta = \ldots, 20^{\circ}, 100^{\circ}, 140^{\circ}, 220^{\circ}, \ldots$$